Mayer-Vietoris sequence on chain complexes of modules
I am trying to solve the following exercise:
The following is a commutative square of chain complexes of modules, where $\ker(f)=0$
$\require{AMScd} 
\def\coker{\operatorname{coker}}$
\begin{CD}
A_\bullet @>{f_\bullet}>> B_\bullet \\
@V{g_\bullet}VV @VV{s_\bullet}V \\
C_\bullet @>>{r_\bullet}> D_\bullet
\end{CD}
Assume that the induced morphism $\coker(f_\bullet) \to \coker(r_\bullet)$ is a quasi-isomorphism. Prove that there exists a long exact sequence:
$$
\cdots \to H_n(A_\bullet) 
\to H_n(B_\bullet) \oplus H_n(C_\bullet) 
\to H_n(D_\bullet) 
\to H_{n−1}(A_\bullet) \to \cdots
$$
I know that the result would be immediate from the snake lemma if I had a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to A_\bullet \to B_\bullet \oplus C_\bullet \to D_\bullet \to 0, 
$$
however, I suspect that the condition about the cokernels is not enough for that. I figured that I can obtain the morphism $H_n(D_\bullet) \to H_{n−1}(A_\bullet)$ from the fact that
$$
0 \to A_\bullet \to B_\bullet \to \coker(f_\bullet) \to 0 
$$
is a short exact sequence, so I obtain a long exact sequence:
$$
\cdots \to H_n(A_\bullet) 
\to H_n(B_\bullet) 
\to H_n(\coker(f_\bullet)) 
\to H_{n−1}(A_\bullet) \to \cdots
$$
And then the isomorphism of homologies of cokernels can be composed with the induced morphism $H_n(D_\bullet) \to H_n(\coker(r_\bullet))$. However, I have no clue how to show that
$$
H_n(A_\bullet) \to H_n(B_\bullet) \oplus H_n(C_\bullet) \to H_n(D_\bullet)
$$
is exact. I'm not sure how to use the fact that homologies of cokernels are isomorphic here, I don't see how that info is relevant for this particular issue and nothing other than diagram chasing comes to my mind, but that got me nowhere.

I've seen a result like this, but along with the assumption that $\ker r_\bullet = 0$. Then you get a map of short exact sequences of chain complexes, hence a map of long exact sequences in homology, with one out of every three maps being an isomorphism. That leads to the desired long exact sequence.
I think that as stated, this is false. If $A_\bullet = B_\bullet = 0$ and $r_\bullet$ is onto (so it has zero cokernel) but not a quasi-isomorphism, then your hypotheses are satisfied, but you're supposed to get a long exact sequence
$$
\cdots \to 0 \to H_n C \to H_n D \to 0 \to \cdots
$$

It does look to be false if I also take $D_∙ = 0$ and $C_∙$ to be anything that is not an exact sequence. Thank you for pointing that out, I will need to consult the source of this exercise.
